# Correcting Text In an Oracle Long Column

Tags: sql, oracle10g

(Yes, I know, Long is deprecated in favor of Clob. Unfortunately, we can't change that right now.)

I have a table with a Long column that holds text representing a domain-specific language. This language supports IF/THEN/ELSE constructs and single-line comments (represented by "--").

Here is an example:

```
IF PERSON_AGE>=21 THEN \r\n
    RETURN OK \r\n
ELSE \r\n
    RETURN NOT_OK ENDIF \r\n
```

Often, users need to modify this text. One of the things they will do is comment out an IF/THEN/ELSE block by sticking the comment token in there.

Unfortunately, due to a bug in a previous version of the client, a line break was introduced into the text held by the LONG column. This in turn makes the ANTLR-based parser lose its mind.

So now, the text will look like this:

```
-- IF PERSON_AGE>=21 THEN \r\n
--    RETURN OK \r\n
-- ELSE \r\n
    RETURN NOT_OK ENDIF
```

This causes what we have named the "dangling ENDIF" issue. The parser blows up on it, and we do not wish to regenerate the grammar and various visitors, as the bug has been corrected in the newer client.

The customer is insisting on a script to fix this, rather than correcting the problem in the database itself. Does Oracle provide a function to make this an easy fix? I knox I can do a Regular Expression based search, but how do I rewrite the text?

Comment: if you can do the regex - then regex_replace.. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm